# Demo login and logout app with AngularJS front end JAX-RS backend

Tags: angularjs, jax-rs

Could somebody please suggest me where can I find a simple demo login and logout app with AngularJS front end and JAX-RS back end.

I have build demo login and logout app with jsf and ejb, but have no idea how to do the same using AngularJS front end and JAX-RS back end (As everything is becoming stateless so just want to try my hand at this).

Could somebody please suggest any such demo app on Github or anywhere else.